# Error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing

I have a problem that prevents me from moving forward and I don't know how to solve it. I have a class called Validator where I store validation functions and I need to do unit tests for each one and validate its functionality, but there are some of them that use the Spring Environment instance in which it accesses the properties file. If I do "normal" unit tests, whenever I call the function where this feature is implemented, it returns me Environment is null. I have tried using **@Autowired** instead of instantiating with **new** in the test class, the use of **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)** and since the test classes and the function classes are in different packages I have also used the **@ComponentScan** and it gives me an error... What am I doing wrong or what am I doing wrong?

I have the code of the Validator class in this way:

```
@Component
public class Validator {
        
    @Autowired
    public Environment env;
    
    public CodRespuestaWS validateTypeOperation(TypeOperation typeOperation, String operation) {
        
        String response = env.getProperty(typeOperation.toString() + "." + operation);
        if (OK.equalsIgnoreCase(response)) {
            return new CodResponseWS();
        }
        return new CodResponseWS(CodResponseWS.ER100, typeOperation.toString()+" not allowed:" + operation);
    }

}
```

And in the test I do it this way:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.functions.validators")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

public class ValidateRequestHigh {

    RequestHigh requestHigh = new RequestHigh();
    CodResponseWS response;
    @Autowired Validator validator;
    
    HighValidator highValidator = new HighValidator();
    UserData userData = new UserData();
    
    
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        response = validator.validateTypeOperation(TypeOperation.typeOperationHigh, "high");
        System.out.println(response.getCodResponse());
    }
}
```

The problem that I mentioned before the NULL, is that when executing the test it did not even reach the print that I have set, but rather it stayed on the line

> String response = env.getProperty(typeOperation.toString() + "." +
> operation);

And it marked the error that **env** was **NULL** and now it returns a different one

And the error that returns me now is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'functiontest.unittest.ValidateRequestHighTest': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'validator'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.functions.validators.Validator'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I guess it's already understood, but I'll detail it more just in case, the functions are in

***src/main/java/com.functions.validators/Validators.java***

and the tests

***src/main/test/functiontest.unittest/ValidateRequestHighTest.java***

I am using version 5.1.2.RELEASE of SpringBoot and JUnit 4

Answer (score 0):

Using field injection makes `Validator` class impossible to be unit tested because it provides no way to pass the `Environment` instance to it. but you can spin up the whole application context and configure it to do dependency injection stuff using `@SpringBootTest` which is not a unit test but integration test.

> if I do "normal" unit tests, whenever I call the function where this
> feature is implemented, it returns me Environment is null.

Because when you use `new` to instantiate a bean its not a Spring managed bean anymore and its dependencies are not resolved.

> I have tried using @Autowired instead of instantiating with new in the
> test class, the use of @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and since the test
> classes and the function classes are in different packages I have also
> used the @ComponentScan and it gives me an error

You should also add `SpringBootTest` annotation for loading into application context.

If you want to really unit test your class you don't need application context instead do the following

Change the `Validator` class like:

```
@Component
public class Validator {

  
  private Environment env;

  public Validator(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
  }

....
}
```

And for unit testing it do:

```
public class ValidatorTest {

  Validator validator;
  MockEnvironment environment;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    environment = new MockEnvironment();
    environment.setProperty("key1", "value1");
    //...
    environment.setProperty("keyn", "valuen");
    validator = new Validator(environment);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // test stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: In the Validator class when I declare the Environment variable I have the @Autowired annotation and in the examples you indicate you remove it, what would happen if you don't delete it?

Comment: @Wail I explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, I had not understood, now yes. I have tried with the example that you have given me and it works, but since I have many classes that extend Validator I have to add the constructor and pass the Environment to it as well, I don't think it will hurt in the long run. Before posting the question I tried @SpringBootTest too but it gave me an error. Could you explain if you want, what is the difference between MockEnvironment and Environment ?

Comment: @Wail what was your error when using @SpringBootTest? 
when you want to unit test your class and it has external dependencies, in your case `Environment` object, you should substitute those external dependencies with mock objects in order to isolate the object being tested with other parts of the system and focus on that object. sometimes there is a mock implementation that you can use and it makes life easy, sometimes you should implement it using Mockito framework for example. you can explore some examples using mockenvironment

Comment: here(https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.mock.env.MockEnvironment)

Comment: This error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'functiontest.unittest.ValidateRequestHighTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'validator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.functions.validators.Validator' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: And there are times that it doesn't even show me the error directly, it runs the test and indicates "terminated" but the printf doesn't show it or the result of the operation. Thanks for the Mock explanation I appreciate it

Comment: @Wail you should update you question with all your attempts.